# Bash command: export BLAS_LIBS="-L$LAPACKHOME/lib -lblas"

Tags: linux, bash, lapack, blas

Can any body explain to me what does the whole sentence mean?

I know this is to set Macro BLAS_LIBS as another string.

But I'm not sure what's the "-lblas" mean and I don't know how to use it.
Similar as the following code. "-llapack"

```
export LAPACK_LIBS="-L$LAPACKHOME/lib -llapack"
```

How can the program find out the BLAS and LAPACK libraries just by "-lblas" and "-llapack" ?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: That's setting the `LAPACK_LIBS` environment variable and marking it for export to processes spawned by your shell. Those are arguments to a compiler and will be used by something (probably `make`) later.

Comment: Hi Etan. Thanks for the explain. But I don't quite understand how does the shell know which library file I'm talking about. In the directory, there exists few library files(*.a). How does the shell know which I'm referring to?

Comment: The shell doesn't know anything. It doesn't care. That's a variable for something *else* to care about. Specifically, your compiler. If you want to understand how those options work go read the documentation for the compiler that ends up using them.

Comment: Thanks Etan. So if i'm using gcc compiler, this variable will then pass to the gcc compiler. gcc is the one who took care of this.

Comment: Assuming that environment variable is being used in a `gcc` command that is run (by a makefile or whatever) at a later time, yes.

Comment: More specifically, gcc by itself probably has no idea about this particular environment variable, but something which is driving the compilation process is configured through these variables and somehow ultimately passes them to the compiler.  The value, but not the variable name, looks like it's going to end up being passed verbatim to the compiler command line.

Comment: @tripleee . Thanks for your explanation. Let me try to interpret your answer. It means the some staff, maybe a piece of codes, reads the variable('-lblas') and set the compiler(gcc) based on the information carried by the variable('-lblas'). So '-lblas' is not direct pass to the compiler. Right? (PS: Why do people make this so complicated?)

Comment: No, I mean something is literally running `gcc $LAPACK_LIBS` ... probably in the project's `Makefile`.  Linking to the code you are discussing would make it a lot easier to reason about it without speculation.

Comment: Not sure what sort of response you need or expect for the parenthetical. Configurability and flexibility as well as tradition and backwards compatibility are probably the drivers for this complexity; though I don't really see what you think is very complicated here, especially compared to the numerical computation you are apparently preparing for.

Comment: Just to clear up a possible misunderstanding regarding my earlier comment, I meant that `LAPACK_LIBS` is not an environment variable `gcc` itself uses or recognizes, so we assume it will be passed to it explicitly somehow.  The value of the variable clearly looks like `gcc` options so it's reasonable to assume that that is what it is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say "just by `-llapack`" because that's not what is happening here.  Specifically, the `-L` option just before it specifies a directory path to add to the library resolution path.  This works roughly like `PATH` in the shell.

For example, with the command line fragment `gcc -Lfoodir -Lbardir -lfoo -lbar`, you basically instruct the linker to search the directories `foodir` and `bardir` for the library files `libfoo.a` and `libbar.a`.

The `-l` option is described in [GCC: Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.2/gcc_2.html#SEC13) and `-L` and friends in the following section [GCC: Options for Directory Search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.2/gcc_2.html#SEC14).

This build arrangement -- configure the build to show where the required files are before compiling -- is common for libraries, where if a user has already downloaded and compiled a required library for some other project, they don't need to rebuild it; they can just point the compiler to wherever they already have the stuff needed for this project.

Building your own libraries is becoming increasingly unnecessary anyway, as prepackaged binaries of most common libraries are available for most systems these days.  But of course, if you are on an unusual platform, or have specialized needs which dictate recompilation with different options than any available prebuilt binary, you will still need to understand how to do this.